# how to nginx reverse proxy\redirect subdomain to subdirectory?

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system, reverse-proxy

I've got a substack newsletter with a CNAME record pointing to `newsletter.identosphere.net`

I want that content to be displayed from `identosphere.net/newsletter` so the user can access each newsletter as a part of my main site:

`identosphere.net/newsletter/issue-13/` should display content from `newsletter.identosphere.net/issue-13/`

Moreover, **if possible** (whether by nginx or dns) *I want to redirect subdomain traffic to its folder on the root domain*.

**Right now I'm using:**

```
location /newsletter/ {
    proxy_pass        http://newsletter.identosphere.net/;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-error.log;
}
```

**What happens with this setting:**

I type https://identosphere.net/newsletter and am redirected to https://newsletter.identosphere.net/

---

### As requested by [@ppuschmann](https://serverfault.com/users/19575/ppuschmann), I'm posting the rest of my nginx config.

What I didn't mention, is that I'm using [MailInABox](https://github.com/mail-in-a-box/mailinabox/) its a selfhosted e-mail service that includes a web-server and dns.

Mainly, customizations are done via gui. I am using an unsupported feature that allows some customization of your config, but not of the main config, which is regularly refreshed. Apparently I cannot add server blocks to my "nginx user-config", only location blocks.

At this point, I'm not expecting to solve this, but if possible I'd like to determine how the dns ([NSD](https://www.nlnetlabs.nl/projects/nsd/about/)) re-direct is set thats preventing my reverse proxy.

#### Here is the NGINX config

As stated in the comments, I can't edit this file, but I can add instructions via a config located elsewhere.

`/etc/nginx/conf.d/local.conf`

```
## NOTE: This file is automatically generated by Mail-in-a-Box.
##       Do not edit this file. It is continually updated by
##       Mail-in-a-Box and your changes will be lost.
##
##       Mail-in-a-Box machines are not meant to be modified.
##       If you modify any system configuration you are on
##       your own --- please do not ask for help from us.

upstream php-fpm {
    server unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
}
## identosphere.net

# Redirect all HTTP to HTTPS *except* the ACME challenges (Let's Encrypt TLS certificate
# domain validation challenges) path, which must be served over HTTP per the ACME spec
# (due to some Apache vulnerability).
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name identosphere.net;
    root /tmp/invalid-path-nothing-here;

    # Improve privacy: Hide version an OS information on
    # error pages and in the "Server" HTTP-Header.
    server_tokens off;

    location / {
        # Redirect using the 'return' directive and the built-in
        # variable '$request_uri' to avoid any capturing, matching
        # or evaluation of regular expressions.
        return 301 https://identosphere.net$request_uri;
    }

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        # This path must be served over HTTP for ACME domain validation.
        # We map this to a special path where our TLS cert provisioning
        # tool knows to store challenge response files.
        alias /home/user-data/ssl/lets_encrypt/webroot/.well-known/acme-challenge/;
    }
}

# The secure HTTPS server.
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name identosphere.net;

    # Improve privacy: Hide version an OS information on
    # error pages and in the "Server" HTTP-Header.
    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate /home/user-data/ssl/ssl_certificate.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/user-data/ssl/ssl_private_key.pem;

    root /home/user-data/www/default;

    # ssl files sha1: 4d28ac1a16c0e04772557f6a765cbaa2e4a1d96f / a2eda6be4854a2530dc96a579325f3e95160fc48
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000" always;
    include /home/user-data/www/identosphere.net.conf;
    
    # Control Panel
    # Proxy /admin to our Python based control panel daemon. It is
    # listening on IPv4 only so use an IP address and not 'localhost'.
    location /admin/assets {
        alias /usr/local/lib/mailinabox/vendor/assets;
    }
    rewrite ^/admin$ /admin/;
    rewrite ^/admin/munin$ /admin/munin/ redirect;
    location /admin/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:10222/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        add_header X-Frame-Options "DENY";
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
        add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'none';";
    }

    # Roundcube Webmail configuration.
    rewrite ^/mail$ /mail/ redirect;
    rewrite ^/mail/$ /mail/index.php;
    location /mail/ {
        index index.php;
        alias /usr/local/lib/roundcubemail/;
    }
    location ~ /mail/config/.* {
        # A ~-style location is needed to give this precedence over the next block.
        return 403;
    }
    location ~ /mail/.*\.php {
        # note: ~ has precendence over a regular location block
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^/mail(/.*)()$;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/local/lib/roundcubemail/$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm;

        # Outgoing mail also goes through this endpoint, so increase the maximum
        # file upload limit to match the corresponding Postfix limit.
        client_max_body_size 128M;
    }

    # Nextcloud configuration.
    rewrite ^/cloud$ /cloud/ redirect;
    rewrite ^/cloud/$ /cloud/index.php;
    rewrite ^/cloud/(contacts|calendar|files)$ /cloud/index.php/apps/$1/ redirect;
    rewrite ^(/cloud/core/doc/[^\/]+/)$ $1/index.html;
    rewrite ^(/cloud/oc[sm]-provider)/$ $1/index.php redirect;
    location /cloud/ {
        alias /usr/local/lib/owncloud/;
        location ~ ^/cloud/(build|tests|config|lib|3rdparty|templates|data|README)/ {
            deny all;
        }
        location ~ ^/cloud/(?:\.|autotest|occ|issue|indie|db_|console) {
            deny all;
        }
        # Enable paths for service and cloud federation discovery
        # Resolves warning in Nextcloud Settings panel
        location ~ ^/cloud/(oc[sm]-provider)?/([^/]+\.php)$ {
            index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/local/lib/owncloud/$1/$2;
            fastcgi_pass php-fpm;
        }
    }
    location ~ ^(/cloud)((?:/ocs)?/[^/]+\.php)(/.*)?$ {
        # note: ~ has precendence over a regular location block
        # Accept URLs like:
        # /cloud/index.php/apps/files/
        # /cloud/index.php/apps/files/ajax/scan.php (it's really index.php; see 6fdef379adfdeac86cc2220209bdf4eb9562268d)
        # /cloud/ocs/v1.php/apps/files_sharing/api/v1 (see #240)
        # /cloud/remote.php/webdav/yourfilehere...
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/local/lib/owncloud/$2;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $1$2;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $3;
        fastcgi_param MOD_X_ACCEL_REDIRECT_ENABLED on;
        fastcgi_param MOD_X_ACCEL_REDIRECT_PREFIX /owncloud-xaccel;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 630;
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm;
        client_max_body_size 1G;
        fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;
    }
    location ^~ /owncloud-xaccel/ {
        # This directory is for MOD_X_ACCEL_REDIRECT_ENABLED. Nextcloud sends the full file
        # path on disk as a subdirectory under this virtual path.
        # We must only allow 'internal' redirects within nginx so that the filesystem
        # is not exposed to the world.
        internal;
        alias /;
    }
    location ~ ^/((caldav|carddav|webdav).*)$ {
        # Z-Push doesn't like getting a redirect, and a plain rewrite didn't work either.
        # Properly proxying like this seems to work fine.
        proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1/cloud/remote.php/$1;
    }
    rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta /cloud/public.php?service=host-meta last;
    rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta.json /cloud/public.php?service=host-meta-json last;
    rewrite ^/.well-known/carddav /cloud/remote.php/carddav/ redirect;
    rewrite ^/.well-known/caldav /cloud/remote.php/caldav/ redirect;

    location = /robots.txt {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /mailinabox.mobileconfig {
        alias /var/lib/mailinabox/mobileconfig.xml;
    }
    location = /.well-known/autoconfig/mail/config-v1.1.xml {
        alias /var/lib/mailinabox/mozilla-autoconfig.xml;
    }
    location = /mail/config-v1.1.xml {
        alias /var/lib/mailinabox/mozilla-autoconfig.xml;
    }
    location = /.well-known/mta-sts.txt {
        alias /var/lib/mailinabox/mta-sts.txt;
    }

    # Z-Push (Microsoft Exchange ActiveSync)
    location /Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/local/lib/z-push/index.php;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "include_path=.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/awl/inc";
        fastcgi_read_timeout 630;
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm;

        # Outgoing mail also goes through this endpoint, so increase the maximum
        # file upload limit to match the corresponding Postfix limit.
        client_max_body_size 128M;
    }
    location ~* ^/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/local/lib/z-push/autodiscover/autodiscover.php;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "include_path=.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/awl/inc";
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm;
    }

    # Disable viewing dotfiles (.htaccess, .svn, .git, etc.)
    # This block is placed at the end. Nginx's precedence rules means this block
    # takes precedence over all non-regex matches and only regex matches that
    # come after it (i.e. none of those, since this is the last one.) That means
    # we're blocking dotfiles in the static hosted sites but not the FastCGI-
    # handled locations for Nextcloud (which serves user-uploaded files that might
    # have this pattern, see #414) or some of the other services.
    location ~ /\.(ht|svn|git|hg|bzr) {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
        deny all;
    }
}
## autoconfig.identosphere.net

# Redirect all HTTP to HTTPS *except* the ACME challenges (Let's Encrypt TLS certificate
# domain validation challenges) path, which must be served over HTTP per the ACME spec
# (due to some Apache vulnerability).
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name autoconfig.identosphere.net;
    root /tmp/invalid-path-nothing-here;

    # Improve privacy: Hide version an OS information on
    # error pages and in the "Server" HTTP-Header.
    server_tokens off;

    location / {
        # Redirect using the 'return' directive and the built-in
        # variable '$request_uri' to avoid any capturing, matching
        # or evaluation of regular expressions.
        return 301 https://autoconfig.identosphere.net$request_uri;
    }

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        # This path must be served over HTTP for ACME domain validation.
        # We map this to a special path where our TLS cert provisioning
        # tool knows to store challenge response files.
        alias /home/user-data/ssl/lets_encrypt/webroot/.well-known/acme-challenge/;
    }
}

# The secure HTTPS server.
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name autoconfig.identosphere.net;

    # Improve privacy: Hide version an OS information on
    # error pages and in the "Server" HTTP-Header.
    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate /home/user-data/ssl/identosphere.net-20210401-90d5ae2d.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/user-data/ssl/ssl_private_key.pem;

    root /home/user-data/www/default;

    # ssl files sha1: 4d28ac1a16c0e04772557f6a765cbaa2e4a1d96f / a2eda6be4854a2530dc96a579325f3e95160fc48
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000" always;
    include /home/user-data/www/autoconfig.identosphere.net.conf;

    location = /robots.txt {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /mailinabox.mobileconfig {
        alias /var/lib/mailinabox/mobileconfig.xml;
    }
    location = /.well-known/autoconfig/mail/config-v1.1.xml {
        alias /var/lib/mailinabox/mozilla-autoconfig.xml;
    }
    location = /mail/config-v1.1.xml {
        alias /var/lib/mailinabox/mozilla-autoconfig.xml;
    }
    location = /.well-known/mta-sts.txt {
        alias /var/lib/mailinabox/mta-sts.txt;
    }

    # Z-Push (Microsoft Exchange ActiveSync)
    location /Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/local/lib/z-push/index.php;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "include_path=.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/awl/inc";
        fastcgi_read_timeout 630;
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm;

        # Outgoing mail also goes through this endpoint, so increase the maximum
        # file upload limit to match the corresponding Postfix limit.
        client_max_body_size 128M;
    }
    location ~* ^/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/local/lib/z-push/autodiscover/autodiscover.php;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "include_path=.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/awl/inc";
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm;
    }

    # Disable viewing dotfiles (.htaccess, .svn, .git, etc.)
    # This block is placed at the end. Nginx's precedence rules means this block
    # takes precedence over all non-regex matches and only regex matches that
    # come after it (i.e. none of those, since this is the last one.) That means
    # we're blocking dotfiles in the static hosted sites but not the FastCGI-
    # handled locations for Nextcloud (which serves user-uploaded files that might
    # have this pattern, see #414) or some of the other services.
    location ~ /\.(ht|svn|git|hg|bzr) {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
        deny all;
    }
}
## autodiscover.identosphere.net

# Redirect all HTTP to HTTPS *except* the ACME challenges (Let's Encrypt TLS certificate
# domain validation challenges) path, which must be served over HTTP per the ACME spec
# (due to some Apache vulnerability).
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name autodiscover.identosphere.net;
    root /tmp/invalid-path-nothing-here;

    # Improve privacy: Hide version an OS information on
    # error pages and in the "Server" HTTP-Header.
    server_tokens off;

    location / {
        # Redirect using the 'return' directive and the built-in
        # variable '$request_uri' to avoid any capturing, matching
        # or evaluation of regular expressions.
        return 301 https://autodiscover.identosphere.net$request_uri;
    }

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        # This path must be served over HTTP for ACME domain validation.
        # We map this to a special path where our TLS cert provisioning
        # tool knows to store challenge response files.
        alias /home/user-data/ssl/lets_encrypt/webroot/.well-known/acme-challenge/;
    }
}

# The secure HTTPS server.
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name autodiscover.identosphere.net;

    # Improve privacy: Hide version an OS information on
    # error pages and in the "Server" HTTP-Header.
    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate /home/user-data/ssl/identosphere.net-20210401-90d5ae2d.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/user-data/ssl/ssl_private_key.pem;

    root /home/user-data/www/default;

    # ssl files sha1: 4d28ac1a16c0e04772557f6a765cbaa2e4a1d96f / a2eda6be4854a2530dc96a579325f3e95160fc48
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000" always;
    include /home/user-data/www/autodiscover.identosphere.net.conf;

    location = /robots.txt {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /mailinabox.mobileconfig {
        alias /var/lib/mailinabox/mobileconfig.xml;
    }
    location = /.well-known/autoconfig/mail/config-v1.1.xml {
        alias /var/lib/mailinabox/mozilla-autoconfig.xml;
    }
    location = /mail/config-v1.1.xml {
        alias /var/lib/mailinabox/mozilla-autoconfig.xml;
    }
    location = /.well-known/mta-sts.txt {
        alias /var/lib/mailinabox/mta-sts.txt;
    }

    # Z-Push (Microsoft Exchange ActiveSync)
    location /Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/local/lib/z-push/index.php;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "include_path=.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/awl/inc";
        fastcgi_read_timeout 630;
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm;

        # Outgoing mail also goes through this endpoint, so increase the maximum
        # file upload limit to match the corresponding Postfix limit.
        client_max_body_size 128M;
    }
    location ~* ^/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/local/lib/z-push/autodiscover/autodiscover.php;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "include_path=.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/awl/inc";
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm;
    }

    # Disable viewing dotfiles (.htaccess, .svn, .git, etc.)
    # This block is placed at the end. Nginx's precedence rules means this block
    # takes precedence over all non-regex matches and only regex matches that
    # come after it (i.e. none of those, since this is the last one.) That means
    # we're blocking dotfiles in the static hosted sites but not the FastCGI-
    # handled locations for Nextcloud (which serves user-uploaded files that might
    # have this pattern, see #414) or some of the other services.
    location ~ /\.(ht|svn|git|hg|bzr) {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
        deny all;
    }
}
## mta-sts.identosphere.net

# Redirect all HTTP to HTTPS *except* the ACME challenges (Let's Encrypt TLS certificate
# domain validation challenges) path, which must be served over HTTP per the ACME spec
# (due to some Apache vulnerability).
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name mta-sts.identosphere.net;
    root /tmp/invalid-path-nothing-here;

    # Improve privacy: Hide version an OS information on
    # error pages and in the "Server" HTTP-Header.
    server_tokens off;

    location / {
        # Redirect using the 'return' directive and the built-in
        # variable '$request_uri' to avoid any capturing, matching
        # or evaluation of regular expressions.
        return 301 https://mta-sts.identosphere.net$request_uri;
    }

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        # This path must be served over HTTP for ACME domain validation.
        # We map this to a special path where our TLS cert provisioning
        # tool knows to store challenge response files.
        alias /home/user-data/ssl/lets_encrypt/webroot/.well-known/acme-challenge/;
    }
}

# The secure HTTPS server.
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name mta-sts.identosphere.net;

    # Improve privacy: Hide version an OS information on
    # error pages and in the "Server" HTTP-Header.
    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate /home/user-data/ssl/identosphere.net-20210401-90d5ae2d.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/user-data/ssl/ssl_private_key.pem;

    root /home/user-data/www/default;

    # ssl files sha1: 4d28ac1a16c0e04772557f6a765cbaa2e4a1d96f / a2eda6be4854a2530dc96a579325f3e95160fc48
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000" always;
    include /home/user-data/www/mta-sts.identosphere.net.conf;

    location = /robots.txt {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /mailinabox.mobileconfig {
        alias /var/lib/mailinabox/mobileconfig.xml;
    }
    location = /.well-known/autoconfig/mail/config-v1.1.xml {
        alias /var/lib/mailinabox/mozilla-autoconfig.xml;
    }
    location = /mail/config-v1.1.xml {
        alias /var/lib/mailinabox/mozilla-autoconfig.xml;
    }
    location = /.well-known/mta-sts.txt {
        alias /var/lib/mailinabox/mta-sts.txt;
    }

    # Z-Push (Microsoft Exchange ActiveSync)
    location /Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/local/lib/z-push/index.php;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "include_path=.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/awl/inc";
        fastcgi_read_timeout 630;
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm;

        # Outgoing mail also goes through this endpoint, so increase the maximum
        # file upload limit to match the corresponding Postfix limit.
        client_max_body_size 128M;
    }
    location ~* ^/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/local/lib/z-push/autodiscover/autodiscover.php;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "include_path=.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/awl/inc";
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm;
    }

    # Disable viewing dotfiles (.htaccess, .svn, .git, etc.)
    # This block is placed at the end. Nginx's precedence rules means this block
    # takes precedence over all non-regex matches and only regex matches that
    # come after it (i.e. none of those, since this is the last one.) That means
    # we're blocking dotfiles in the static hosted sites but not the FastCGI-
    # handled locations for Nextcloud (which serves user-uploaded files that might
    # have this pattern, see #414) or some of the other services.
    location ~ /\.(ht|svn|git|hg|bzr) {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
        deny all;
    }
}
## www.identosphere.net

# Redirect all HTTP to HTTPS *except* the ACME challenges (Let's Encrypt TLS certificate
# domain validation challenges) path, which must be served over HTTP per the ACME spec
# (due to some Apache vulnerability).
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name www.identosphere.net;
    root /tmp/invalid-path-nothing-here;

    # Improve privacy: Hide version an OS information on
    # error pages and in the "Server" HTTP-Header.
    server_tokens off;

    location / {
        # Redirect using the 'return' directive and the built-in
        # variable '$request_uri' to avoid any capturing, matching
        # or evaluation of regular expressions.
        return 301 https://www.identosphere.net$request_uri;
    }

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        # This path must be served over HTTP for ACME domain validation.
        # We map this to a special path where our TLS cert provisioning
        # tool knows to store challenge response files.
        alias /home/user-data/ssl/lets_encrypt/webroot/.well-known/acme-challenge/;
    }
}

# The secure HTTPS server.
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name www.identosphere.net;

    # Improve privacy: Hide version an OS information on
    # error pages and in the "Server" HTTP-Header.
    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate /home/user-data/ssl/identosphere.net-20210401-90d5ae2d.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/user-data/ssl/ssl_private_key.pem;

    rewrite ^(.*) https://identosphere.net$1 permanent;
}
```

Comment: Please post more details of your Nginx-config. 
https://identosphere.net/newsletter does not match on location /newsletter/

Answer (score 1):

You need to at least set:

```
proxy_set_header Host newsletter.identosphere.net;
```

This sends the correct `Host` header to the upstream server, which might be configured to send redirects when there is an incorrect `Host` header in the request.

Comment: sorry, this gives the same result, redirect from identosphere.net/newsletter to newsletter.identosphere.net

Comment: Then the `newsletter.identosphere.net` host configuration must be changed so that it doesn't send those redirects.

Comment: I have set through DNS on the same machine. I don't even know where to begin looking for that configuration, though.

Comment: It is not DNS. The site `newsletter.identosphere.net` is hosted on some server. You need to modify the application on that server so that it knows what is its proper root URL.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a server block within the Nginx config, then using the Reverse Proxy. It even allows a port redirection, which is just fantastic.

Here's an exceprt regarding a live website, from my config file at `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` :

```
server {
    server_name   wows-karma.com www.wows-karma.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:5021;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

server {
    server_name   api.wows-karma.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:5020/api/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
```

This example (which is a real, live and working website by the way) should be enough material to cover your usecase. I'd suggest you follow the API example, and adapt it to your needs.

Oh and also, that Reverse Proxy works also on remote destinations, not just local. Think about the possibilities...

Comment: I'm using Mailinabox [1] and do not have the ability to add a server block.. I can only add location blocks. This is an unsupported customization.. so I think I'll just have to live with the subdomain 


[1] https://github.com/mail-in-a-box/mailinabox/